# How do I run a spark sql aggregator cumulatively?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on a project with spark datasets (in Java) where I have to create a new column derived from an accumulator run over all the previous rows.

I have been implementing this using a custom `UserDefinedAggregationFunction` over a Window from `unboundedPreceding` to `currentRow`.

This goes something like this:

```java
df.withColumn("newColumn", customAccumulator
    .apply(columnInputSeq)
    .over(customWindowSpec));
```

However, I would really prefer to use a typed Dataset for type safety reasons and generally cleaner code. i.e: perform the same operation with an `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator` over a `Dataset<CustomType>`. The problem here is I have looked through all the documentation and can't work out how to make it behave in the same way as above (i.e. I can only get a final aggregate over the whole column rather than a cumulative state at each row).

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so, how?

Example added for clarity:

Initial table:

```
+-------+------+------+
| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
+-------+------+------+
|     1 | abc  | def  |
|     2 | ghi  | jkl  |
|     3 | mno  | pqr  |
|     4 | stu  | vwx  |
+-------+------+------+
```

Then with example aggregation operation: 
First reverse the accumulator, prepend Col1 append Col2 and return this value, also setting it as the accumulator.

```
+-------+------+------+--------------------------+
| Index | Col1 | Col2 |       Accumulator        |
+-------+------+------+--------------------------+
|     1 | abc  | def  | abcdef                   |
|     2 | ghi  | jkl  | ghifedcbajkl             |
|     3 | mno  | pqr  | mnolkjabcdefihgpqr       |
|     4 | stu  | vwx  | sturpqghifedcbajklonmvwx |
+-------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Using a `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` I have been able to produce this but with an `Aggregator` I can only get the last row.

Comment: Can you add some information regarding what aggregation youre exactly looking for and some sample dataset?

Comment: @ChitralVerma I have added an example. Please don't just suggest builtins that I can use at that is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't

My source for this is a friend who has been working on an identical problem to this and has now concluded it's impossible

Comment: That's a shame. Could you possibly provide a source too, preferably a link to relevant documentation?

Comment: Not documentation per se but hopefully this will help: https://www.latlmes.com/tech/top-10-java-spark-sql-tricks-1

I can ask my friend for more detail (though I do question his computer science credentials)